# building a water mask

Tags: envi, masking

I'm working with multi-temporal datasets from modis and had to do various vegetation indices. I ran into a problem now because there is a significant amount of water too, which skews the resulting map. How can I build a mask to just blend out the water bodies?

Answer (score 2):

It's been some months since I used ENVI and unfortunately I don't have it available to poke around in right now, but I can recall three ways you could create the mask.  The first would be to use the draw tools in ENVI to create shapes to use as a mask; or more appropriately the [ROI (region of interest) tool](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/regionofinteresttool.html).  The second would be to use GIS software to generate the same and save it as a shapefile, or perhaps locate some water body shape information for your area of interest.  The third would be to run a classification on the image for the purpose of identifying water pixels and then saving the results to a shapefile that could then be used as a mask.

The following links may also help you with specific steps or alternate methods:
http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ManageRasterData.html#Masking
http://hyspeedblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/application-tips-for-envi-5-0-building-a-mask-from-a-classified-image/

You may also wish to edit your question to clarify a couple of things.  What exactly do you mean by 'skews the resulting map' - too much color ramp devoted to water?  When you say 'blend out' you actually mean *cut out*, correct? Which version of ENVI are you using? That may influence methods available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your dataset in MNF. Use 2D scatter plot using MNF components 1 and 2.

Find the water from the scatter plot:

[image: sample 2D scatter plot]

[image: sample mask]